# How to fix no internet access but WLAN connected?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, internet, wifi

I installed a clean Raspian from the newest NOOBS 1.9.1 setup on my Raspberry Pi B+. On boot the WLAN-Dongle is connected. I used the GUI to connect to my WPA2 protected Wireless Network, [like described here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/README.md). The Pi connects to the WLAN and shows me an IP-Address.

But now I cannot connect to the internet. loading `www.google.com` from the browser results in an error. I can also not connect via SSH from my PC using putty into my Pi. From the Pi I can also not ping my routers IP.

I looks like my Pi is totally disconnected although it is showing me an IP-Address an a WLAN-Connection.

I also tried to setup my WLAN via commandline [like described here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md). But this also does not work.

How can I get access to the internet?

Comment: You have told us nothing. What did you actually do? Have you searched this site for similar issues?

Comment: I tried to set up my WLAN like described in the documentation. I also read your question/anwer http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip and many other turorials to setup via commandline, but nothing worked. If you are missing specific config files to help me, please tell me and I can provide them.

Comment: I could ask you lots of questions guessing what you MAY have done,but only you know what you ACTUALLY did.

Comment: I installed raspbian jessies from NOOBs 1.9.1, I clicked on the WiFi symbol in the right upper corner, I selected the WLAN of my router and entered the password in the dialog an pressed OK. That is all that I've done. IP-Address shows up but no Internet connection.

Comment: Add the output of `ip addr show` and `netstat -rn` to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what @ott said doesn't work, Try restarting your router and resetting your Internet modem. Just because you're connected to the network doesn't mean you're connected to the Internet. You should also re-download noobs,  reinstall it,  then try to connect to the Internet. I had a similar issue as you did,  and a fresh installation of noobs fixed it for me. Using Ethernet connection, I would also try `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal.  When that completes,  use `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to ensure you've got the current updates. This could help the wireless issue you're having.

Edit: I ran by this just today. Give this a try. It's straight from adafruit.com.

If you find your module 'drops out' from time to time, you can fix it fairly easily with a command line fix (thanks perseus286!)

Create and edit a new file in /etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf
```

and paste the following in

```
# Disable power saving
options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=1 rtw_ips_mode=1
```

Then reboot with sudo reboot

Comment: after my third reinstall, it worked clean "out of the box". But I did the same steps.

Comment: @Simulant, very good. I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: now after a reboot I am disconnected from the Internet again. I also cannot SSH over LAN into the Pi, but a connection to the WLAN is shown with an IP-Address... :-(

Comment: @Simulant, HMMMMM... I've never run into these kinds of extensive problems. After a reinstall or 2 my Internet works. Perhaps you should not SSH over LAN,  BUT just use the terminal from the Pi directly.

Comment: @Simulant, try this. It looks promising...https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=44044